# Si el usuario no carga foto, no mover nada Laravel

Tags: laravel

Buenas estoy haciendo la edición de un perfil. A este le he añadido un input para cambiar su foto de perfil, funciona bien la subida, pero si modifico el perfil con el formulario pero no cambio la foto me devuelve este error.

```
"call to a member function move() on null"
```

Muestro código.

```
<input accept="image/*" type="file" name="imagen" value="{{ $usuario->foto }}">

    $image = $request->file('imagen');
    $image->move('uploads', $image->getClientOriginalName());
    $usuario->foto = $image->getClientOriginalName();
```

En la base de datos dejo el campo como `null` por que en el registro no eligen foto, se registran solo con email y contraseña.

Hay que hacer un `if else` si el usuario cargo foto??, si es así como tengo que proceder?

Comment: Muchas gracias ahora le doy un vistazo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que es eso, al editar, no estás enviando ninguna imagen en el campo, por eso tenés **null**, lo que podés hacer es evaluar si no tiene valor, por ejemplo;

```
if(!is_null($request->file('imagen'))) {
...
```

Entonces solo en ese caso te actualizará la foto de perfil, lo mismo con el compo password, en el caso de que tambien lo tengan en el mismo formulario, porque lo dejará en null.

Comment: Hola @Javier Snachez , entiendo lo del `IF`, pero hacemos if {  que pongo cundo no recibe nada y luego supongo que un `else` con lo que tengo arriba por que si recibe. Pero que va en el IF

Comment: En realidad si te fijás bien en el IF, ya estás evaluando que si el valor de imagen, NO ES NULO, hacés algo, o sea, actualizas la foto, y no es necesario un ELSE, ya que si no viene ningun valor, es porque el usuario no quiso cambiar su foto, asi que no necesitas cambiar nada.

Comment: Ahhh es verdad! Toda la razón tienes, muchas gracias ahora lo pruebo

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias!